# Making Kohana based mobile site

Tags: php, url-rewriting, kohana, kohana-3

I have a website in Kohana Framework which is working fine. Lets say website is www.mainsite.com 
Now I want to make a mobile version of website on URL www.mainsite.com/mobile.
I have copied all files of mainsite and pasted in a folder MOBILE inside Mainsite.

Here I have done path settings in index.php to define application ,system and modules path.

Now when I run www.mainsite.com/mobile , it works good and I land on mobile view homepage. The problem arises with links and urls, i.e. when I click any link , it redirects me to views inside www.mainsite.com rather than redirecting me to views inside www.mainsite.com/mobilesite.

I am new to kohana. The problem is related to routing as route files in both directories is same. I tried making some changes but in vain. I actually want to mount www.mainsite.com/mobilesite as base directory to open mobile views, but it only showing homepage as mobile view and clicking on links take me to desktop views of mainsite.

Some code from route.php goes as:

```
   $config['_default'] = '/deals/local_deals';  //takes me to homepage of mobile view
   $config['local.html'] = "/deals/local_deals"; 
   $config['local/page/(.*)'] = "/deals/local_deals/$1";
   $config['today-deals.html'] = "/deals/today_deals";
   $config['today-deals/page/(.*)'] = "/deals/today_deals/$1";

   $config['get-aways.html'] = "/deals/get_aways";
   $config['get-aways/page/(.*)'] = "/deals/get_aways/$1";
```

These are some default routes which I need to change for mobile.
I am new with PHP framework and apologise in advance if I am asking something silly.
Thanks in advance for any help and suggestions.

Comment: Did you properply set the `base_url` in bootstrap.php? Also I think this is a bit of an overkill - you are duplicating your whole codebase simply to deliver different views (what should be no problem as Kohana is MVC oriented). Additionally with a responsive layout, you wouldn't even need to cater different views

Comment: @kingkero It is kohana version 2.3.4 . I have done $config['site_domain'] = 'http://mainsite.com/mobile/'; inside mobile>application>config.php but it didnt helped

Comment: I am referring to same modules and system folders for both of versions. For some reasons I need to do it this way.

Comment: @kingkero Yes , the problem was with base url. In .htaccess file it was RewriteBase /mainsite/ , Now I changed it to RewriteBase /mainsite/mobilesite/. Really bad of me. Wasted a lot of time because of small mistake. Thanks for your suggestions. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found answer to this.

The problem was with base url. In .htaccess file of mobile site folder it was RewriteBase /mainsite/ , Now I changed it to RewriteBase /mainsite/mobilesite/.And now its working fine for me.